# Nested object update query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nested

I have object in my `procedures` collection.

I want to update item_status of item_id `5996c80fca423ce1228f7690` which is available in `preferences.items`.

I want to get all records who has mentioned `item_id` so that we can update all occurrences.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5996d0a1ca423ce1228f777a"), 
    "status" : "Active", 
    "procedure_name" : "ATHA", 
    "procedure_for" : "Admin", 
    "created_by" : "5940c3e8734d1d79866338cf", 
    "created_on" : ISODate("2017-10-19T18:44:22.702+0000"), 
    "speciality_id" : "5751131e3a1253845560a984", 
    "speciality" : "Orthopdics", 
    "master_template_id" : "", 
    "hospital_id" : "", 
    "surgeon_nurse_id" : "", 
    "procedure_type" : "Published", 
    "published_on" : ISODate("2017-10-19T18:44:22.702+0000"), 
    "surgical_sequence" : [

    ], 
    "preferences" : [


        {
            "category_id" : "5971fae84658f5241d8a5b70", 
            "category" : "Instruments", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59e8f2861c999f292a837304"), 
            "items" : [

                {
                    "item_id" : "5996c80fca423ce1228f7690", 
                    "item_name" : "Battery", 
                    "item_description" : "", 
                    "image_name" : "BATTERY.png", 
                    "icon_image" : "", 
                    "side_view_image" : "", 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59e8f2861c999f292a837306"), 
                    "attributes" : [

                    ], 
                    "subcategory" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "Power tool", 
                            "subcategory_id" : "5996c80eca423ce1228f7549", 
                            "parent_id" : "", 
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5996c80fca423ce1228f7709")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name" : "Battery", 
                            "subcategory_id" : "5996c80eca423ce1228f750e", 
                            "parent_id" : "5996c80eca423ce1228f7549", 
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5996c80fca423ce1228f7708")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "modified_by" : "5940c3e8734d1d79866338cf", 
    "modified_on" : ISODate("2017-10-19T18:44:22.702+0000")
}
```

Comment: `preference.items` don't have a field called `item_status`. Are you saying you want to update the `status` field ?

Comment: @subodh deshpande cross check ur question and data set? There's no point in giving wrong data set and expecting answers

Comment: Sorry. I just wanted to updated that field whether it exist or not. If its not exist then it will add field in object & then update same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about updating `status` field since I don't find any field with the name `item_status`. If that's the case, the below query should work:

```
> db.procedures.updateMany({"preferences.$.items.$.item_id": "5996c80fca423ce1228f7690"}, {"$set": {"status": "new_status"}})
```

Comment: I have added "item_status" field manually & tried following query.

`db.procedures.updateMany({"preferences.$.items.$.item_id": "5996c80fca423ce1228f7690"}, {"$set": {"item_status": "Open"}})`

Giving me result like
 `{ 
    "acknowledged" : true, 
    "matchedCount" : 0.0, 
    "modifiedCount" : 0.0
}`

None of the row updated.

Comment: The field `item_status` exists in your actual documents?